# gRPC becomes very slow all of a sudden

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I use gRPC for Python RPC on the same machine. It has been working great till yesterday. Then, all of a sudden, it started being very slow. The `helloworld` example now takes about 78s to complete. I tested it on three computers on the same network, all Ubuntu 18.04, with the same results. At home, the same example runs almost instantaneously. I suspect some networking issue, maybe an automatic update on the gateway, but I'm at a loss on how to troubleshoot the problem. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I still don't know what happened, but I found a workaround. Replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` in the `grpc.insecure_channel` connection string makes gRPC responsive again.

Comment: It may help to see what `localhost` resolves to, and compare that to what addresses your server is running on.

Comment: @apolcyn If I try `ping localhost` from the command line, it resolves to `127.0.0.1`